# Pass structure pointer as an argument to a function in c

Tags: c

I am developing a code in which I need to pass a structure pointer value to a function as a parameter. I am calling function "proto485Compare()" in "RS485TaskSlave()". "rs485Msg" contains my data for which I need to verify for checksum, I am checking it in "RS485TaskSlave()" using "if(proto485ValidCheckSum(rs485_message_t ((uint8_t*)message)))" but it is showing error on this line.

Please help me to get the values of "rs485Msg" & check for checksum on this line

Below is my code snippet:

```
 typedef struct
    {
      uint8_t AB;     ///< Address byte (Start byte)
      uint8_t CB;     ///< Command (index) "ASCII-byte"
      uint8_t SI;     ///< Action (sub index) "ASCII-byte"
      uint8_t PH1;    ///< Payload "ASCII-byte" of the high nibble of the high byte of the raw payload
      uint8_t PH0;    ///< Payload "ASCII-byte" of the low nibble of the high byte of the raw payload
      uint8_t PL1;    ///< Payload "ASCII-byte" of the high nibble of the low byte of the raw payload
      uint8_t PL0;    ///< Payload "ASCII-byte" of the low nibble of the low byte of the raw payload
      uint8_t CS1;    ///< Checksum "ASCII-byte" of the high nibble of the raw checksum
      uint8_t CS0;    ///< Checksum "ASCII-byte" of the low nibble of the raw checksum
    } rs485_message_t;

    uint8_t proto485ValidCheckSum(rs485_message_t message)
    { 
      uint8_t rawChecksum = (message.CB - OFFSET_ASCII) + (message.SI - OFFSET_ASCII) +
        (message.PH1 - OFFSET_ASCII) + (message.PH0 - OFFSET_ASCII) +
          (message.PL1 - OFFSET_ASCII) + (message.PL0 - OFFSET_ASCII);

      uint8_t res = (((rawChecksum & 0xF0) >> 4) + OFFSET_ASCII) == message.CS1 &&
        ((rawChecksum & 0x0F) + OFFSET_ASCII) == message.CS0;

      return res;
    }

    void RS485TaskSlave(void *p_arg) //b - RS485 communication Task
    {
        uint8_t res; 
        rs485_message_t rs485Msg;
        uint8_t command, action, value;

        (void)p_arg;
        while(1)
        {      
          res = driver485Read((uint8_t *)&rs485Msg, RS485_MSG_LENGTH); 
          if(RS485_MSG_LENGTH == 9)
         {
            res =  proto485Compare((uint8_t *)&rs485Msg, command, action, value);         
         }
        }      
    }

    int16_t proto485Compare(uint8_t* message, uint8_t* comparec, uint8_t* comparea, uint8_t* comaprev)
    { int j = 0;
      rs485_message_t rs485Msg;
      char res; 
      uint8_t FWmsg[9] = {0x09,0x31,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x33,0x30,0x34};           
      uint8_t arduinodata[9] = {0x09,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30}; 

     if(proto485ValidCheckSum(rs485_message_t ((uint8_t*)message))) //
/*GETTING ERRORVON THIS LINE please help how to pass message value to verify checksum at this line*/
      {
      printf("compare command..........");

        for (j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
          arduinodata[j] = message[j];
          printf("%d ",arduinodata[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        if(compareArray(FWmsg,arduinodata,7)==0)
        {   
          uint8_t add, fwc, fwa;
          uint16_t fwv; 
          res = GetABFWversion(&add, &fwc, &fwa, &fwv);
          res = proto485OnlyWrite(add,fwc, fwa, fwv);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        printf("Arrays have different elements.\n");
      } 
      return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your casting, and change your `message` parameter to be `rs485_message_t *`:

```
int16_t proto485Compare(rs485_message_t * message, uint8_t* comparec, uint8_t* comparea, uint8_t* comaprev) {
    int j = 0;
    rs485_message_t rs485Msg;
    char res; 
    uint8_t FWmsg[9] = {0x09,0x31,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x33,0x30,0x34};           
    uint8_t arduinodata[9] = {0x09,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30,0x30}; 

    if(proto485ValidCheckSum(message))) { ...
```

And when you call it, simply:

```
res =  proto485Compare(&rs485Msg, command, action, value);
```

To get at the individual bytes you can then cast a new variable:

```
uint8_t *messageAsBytes = (uint8_t *)message;
```

Then you can use:

```
messageAsBytes[i]
```

etc.

However another cleaner way is to create a `union` in your structure:

```
struct rs485_message_t {
    union {
        uint8_t bytes[9];
        struct {
            uint8_t AB;     ///< Address byte (Start byte)
            uint8_t CB;     ///< Command (index) "ASCII-byte"
            uint8_t SI;     ///< Action (sub index) "ASCII-byte"
            uint8_t PH1;    ///< Payload "ASCII-byte" of the high nibble of the high byte of the raw payload
            uint8_t PH0;    ///< Payload "ASCII-byte" of the low nibble of the high byte of the raw payload
            uint8_t PL1;    ///< Payload "ASCII-byte" of the high nibble of the low byte of the raw payload
            uint8_t PL0;    ///< Payload "ASCII-byte" of the low nibble of the low byte of the raw payload
            uint8_t CS1;    ///< Checksum "ASCII-byte" of the high nibble of the raw checksum
            uint8_t CS0;    ///< Checksum "ASCII-byte" of the low nibble of the raw checksum
        };
    };
};
```

So you can now access `message->CS0`, etc, as well as `message->bytes[3]`.

You should also pass a pointer when you call `proto485ValidCheckSum` - purely to save memory.

```
uint8_t proto485ValidCheckSum(rs485_message_t *message)
{ 
  uint8_t rawChecksum = (message->CB - OFFSET_ASCII) + (message->SI - OFFSET_ASCII) +
    (message->PH1 - OFFSET_ASCII) + (message->PH0 - OFFSET_ASCII) +
      (message->PL1 - OFFSET_ASCII) + (message->PL0 - OFFSET_ASCII);

  uint8_t res = (((rawChecksum & 0xF0) >> 4) + OFFSET_ASCII) == message->CS1 &&
    ((rawChecksum & 0x0F) + OFFSET_ASCII) == message->CS0;

  return res;
}
```

And again call it with a pointer, which the first block of code does anyway.

In general, it's better to pass a single pointer to a struct around from function to function instead of cloning it each time.

You can also use "pass by reference" if you like, but I find it's better to stick to pointers when passing something around alot like this.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have made above mentioned changed & run the code it is showing below errors....   1) on line  "if(proto485ValidCheckSum(rs485_message_t ((uint8_t*)message)))" it gives "type name is not allowed" and on line " arduinodata[j] = message[j];" it shows that "a value of type "rs485_message_t" cannot be assigned to an entity of tpe "uint8_t" "

Comment: @swanand Read my first code block and compare it to yours.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i have changed for message element reading it is working fine but I am still getting error on line " if(proto485ValidCheckSum(rs485_message_t ((uint8_t*)message)))" t gives "type name is not allowed" Please inform If I am doing something wrong....

Comment: @swanand Read my first code block and compare it to yours.

Comment: Thank you so much once again for providing guidance......